# jQuery element selector returns a list instead of an HTML tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created an HTML document and when I use jQuery I am getting an unexpected result instead of seeing the HTML tag in Google Chrome console.

It worked when I was using Javascript.

Is there a setting I am missing?

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>jQuery Demo</title>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>jQuery Demo</h1>

    <ul>
        <li>Newt</li>
        <li>Howler Monkey<a href="monkey.com"> Monkey.com</a></li>
        <li id="adorable">Pine Marten</li>
    </ul>

    <a href="https://www.google.com">GOOGLE</a>
</body>

</html>
```

The following jQuery code in Google console

```
$("h1")
```

should result in

```
<h1>jQuery Demo</h1>
```

but the result is just a list and 0 gives me the entire object.

The initial open and last close double quotes of each line are there so I can post it as is.

```
"$("h1")"

"k.fn.init [h1, prevObject: k.fn.init(1)]"

"0: h1"

"length: 1"

"prevObject: k.fn.init [document]"

"__proto__: Object(0)"
```

Comment: `$('h1')` gets you a jQuery collection. Try `$('h1').get(0)` to get your desired result. See the docs [here](https://api.jquery.com/get/).

Comment: Your premise is incorrect, `$("h1")` doesn't return a string, but a collection of jQuery objects, because there may be more than 1 `h1` elements in the page.

Comment: Ok, thank you for responding. I found it. dot text() gives me the inner text  and  dot html() gives me the tag. these also allow me to manipulate the code in the browser. I just tried .get(0) thank you.

Comment: whoever posted Try $('h1').get(0) , thank you

Comment: try this : $("h1").html()

Comment: can you mark answer if you find sufficient please

Answer (score 0):

`$('h1')[0]` === `$('h1').get(0)` === DOM object of first element

`$('h1').eq(0)` === first jQuery element

[eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

[get()](https://api.jquery.com/get/)

Comment: You might want to check your doc links. You've linked to the `:eq()` selector, not [method](https://api.jquery.com/eq/), similar but not the same. You've linked to `jQuery.get()` which does an AJAX get, very different to [`.get(index)`](https://api.jquery.com/get/#get-index)